# What is the pin configuration of an Hitachi HN46532-2 Mask ROM?

Tags: rom, documentation

I'm working remotely with a person that has a Canon BX-1 computer from around 1978. He has the computer and I have fuzzy memory of the machine. There is no hardware documentation to be found, so we are reverse engineering it to get a dump of the MASK ROM card.

The six mask ROMS are Hitachi HN46532-2. We have found some information such as it has 12 address lines and 8 data lines for an 8 bit by 4K array. The package is a 28-pin DIP. Tracing the pins and looking at the power points it doesn't seem to match later chips of that size. These have 5V power on pin-14 and 0V on pin-1.

I haven't been able to find an Hitachi datasheet or components handbook that includes this chip or a 28-pin pattern that matches the power configuration.

The card:
[image]

The ROMs:
[image]